# Running PHP in Nginx - PHP directory missing inside /run - ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I am configuring Nginx in Ubuntu to run a PHP file. Nginx currently renders a html page and to render php file I have added the below block in the configuration file (thanks to stack overflow)

```
location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php7.0-cgi alone:
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #   # With php7.0-fpm:
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }
```

When I restart the nginx it fails and the log error says no directory. I noticed that this folder PHP does not exist in the run directory. However, PHP has been installed and php -v is giving me the version as 7.0.33

How do i resolve this issue? Why is this directory missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you installed `php-fpm`? If not `apt install php-fpm` will install it.

If you have installed `php-fpm` the socket should be available, but maybe you use a wrong path. to find out the correct path you can take a look in the fpm config file (`listen =`):

```
cat /etc/php/<version>/fpm/pool.d/www.conf | grep "listen = "
```

Maybe the path differs a bit for you.

Comment: This doesn't work for me.

cat /etc/php/7.3/fpm/pool.d/www.conf | grep "listen = "

listen = /run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock

 ls /run/php

ls: cannot access '/run/php': No such file or directory